# Materialize nav bar dropdown is not consistent in display

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize

Using materialize css in angular 4 project,I have used the following code for dropdown in navbar . Added js code in index.html like the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
      $('.dropdown-button2').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      gutter: ($('.dropdown-content').width()*3)/2.5 + 5, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button

  });
 });
```

template code - monitoring.ts

```
<nav class="cyan  lighten-1">
   <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo" style="margin-left: 12px;font-size: 27px;">  Enterprise Data Management</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down" style="font-size: 13px !important;">
         <li ><a class="dropdown-button drop-size"  data-activates="botMenu" data-belowOrigin="true">Bots<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-button drop-size"  data-activates="monitoringMenu" data-belowOrigin="true">Monitoring<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-button"  data-activates="userMenu" data-belowOrigin="true"><i class="material-icons left">perm_identity</i>User<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="userMenu" class="dropdown-content">
   <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
   <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="botMenu" class="dropdown-content">
   <li><a (click)="showDialog = !showDialog" style="margin-top: -3px;"> Suspicious Bot</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="monitoringMenu" class="dropdown-content">
   <li><a class='dropdown-button2 d' href='#' data-activates='vehicleMenu' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">Vehicle</a></li>
   <li><a class='dropdown-button2 d' href='#' data-activates='deviceMenu' data-hover="hover" data-alignment="left">Device</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id='vehicleMenu' class='dropdown-content'>
     <li><a routerLink="/bsm" routerLinkActive="active"> BSM</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="/bluetoad" routerLinkActive="active"> BlueTOAD</a></li>
   <li ><a routerLink="/sensors" routerLinkActive="active">SBV</a></li>
    <!--<li>SBV</li>-->
</ul>
<ul id='deviceMenu' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li ><a routerLink="/sensors" routerLinkActive="active">Environmental Sensors</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I load the application  9 out of 10 times the dropdown does not load, I have searched related docs, but still not able to fix it. Not only this one , multiple select also does not work consistently. Is this a problem of materialize ?? or is there any problem with angular using materialize???

Comment: Why do you prefer to use materialize with angular  , they are not compatible. If you can change , probably go for MDC for web. Can you show how you are using materialize , how are you loading jquery etc .,

Comment: if it is not compatible y angular provides a module for materilaize https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-materialize

Comment: That is not provided by angular, some developer created it to be used with angular . Materialize works best with jquery . If used with angular you are clubbing two different technologies jquery and angular . If you want to write best angular code you should not be touching jquery

Comment: Why are you using `$('.dropdown-button2').dropdown({` instead of `$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({` ? Change that and see what happens.